# Is there a way include an attribute contained in JSONB with Sequelize.js?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

The second column in the SQL statement below retrieve Platform__c attribute from a JSONB column (entity_json).

When I try to use the syntax `["account_name", "entity_json ->> 'Platform__c'"]` as the column name, it fails. with this error: `"column \"entity_json ->> 'Platform__c'\" does not exist"`

Is there a way in Sequelize.js to retrieve this column using some syntax highlighted in the documentation?

```
SELECT "account_name", entity_json ->> 'Platform__c' test 
FROM "sfdc"."mt_account" AS "Account" WHERE "Account"."account_name" ILIKE
'somecustomer' LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem now with Sequelize 4.44.0 however what works for me is something like this:

```
Account.findAll({
  where: {
    name: {
      [Op.iLike]: 'somecustomer',
    },
  attributes: [
    'id',
    [sequelize.json('entity_json.Platform__c'), 'Platform__c']
  ],
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you'd just like to add a JSONB item to your SELECT with all other attributes you can use the following syntax for your attributes: `attributes: { include: [[sequelize.json('entity_json.Platform__c'), 'Platform__c']] }` Instead of having to include all your columns over again.

Comment: If `Platform__c` is an array, eg `["en", "fr"]`, how to make Sequelize handle it as an array, instead of returning a string escaped value now? `"[\"en\", \"fr\"]"`

Answer (score 0):

try the following syntax

```
SELECT "account_name", "entity_json"#>>'{Platform__c}' test 
    FROM "sfdc"."mt_account" AS "Account" WHERE "Account"."account_name"     ILIKE 'somecustomer' LIMIT 10;
```